# What is the simplest way to stream HTML canvas content

Tags: html, canvas, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, mediastream

I have created simple `canvas` element to draw a string `"Hello World"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can create [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) from this `canvas` by using [`HTMLCanvasElement.captureStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream)

```html
// Find the canvas element to capture
var canvasElt = document.querySelector('myCanvas');

// Get the stream
var stream = canvasElt.captureStream(25); // 25 FPS

// Do things to the stream now
```

How can I use this `stream` to get consumed by VLC or YouTube/Facebook live?

I guess [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) will help me but I dont know how.
I found https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example but this is not looking easy way.

Comment: The canvas streaming example you link to is the easiest, simplest method.